# Toggle this content and hide other content automatically using jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery code toggles the current content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".content").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class content
  $(".heading").click(function()
  {
    $(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/6827/)

I want to toggle (show/hide) the current content while hiding other items with the same class. For this, I added "$(".content").hide();" (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/6828/).) But in this case, when I click an element which is currently shown again, it will not be toggled (hidden) but be shown again.

How can I handle it in this case?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exclude the "current" one from the `hide()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".content").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class content
  $(".heading").click(function()
  {
    $(".content").not($(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500)).hide();
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/eK8X5/6829/

I realise this may look cryptic, so the long version (of the middle line) is:

```
 var $target = $(this).next(".content");
 $(".content").not($target).hide();
 $target.slideToggle(500)
```

Note: You will get a better visual effect if you `slideUp()` and not `hide()` the others:

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".content").hide();
  //toggle the componenet with class content
  $(".heading").click(function()
  {
    $(".content").not($(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500)).slideUp();
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/eK8X5/6832/

Comment: No problem. `.not()` is an extremely useful feature in many cases :)